# Нужно передать значение playerX и playerY из фунуции joysic файла virtjoysic в файл main.py что бы прверять находится ли игрок на определённой клетке

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame

как это сделать?
вот весь код

## main.py

```
import pygame as pg        
import math                 
import random
from pygame import image
from virtjoystick import joystic
sc = pg.display.set_mode((1720,1080), pg.FULLSCREEN | pg.SCALED)

istouch = False     #Создаем переменную чтобы знать нажата мышь\палец или нет
mouse2 = (-1000,-1000)      #Переменная для фиксированого значения мыши

playerX = 200
playerY = 200
while running: 
    mouse = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    for backend in range(30):
        for img in range(35):
            back_rect = back.get_rect(
            bottomright=(img*47, backend*47))
            sc.blit(back, back_rect)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:        #Если мышь\палец нажата
            istouch = True      #Присваиваем истину
            mouse2 = mouse 
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:        #Если мышь\палец отпускаются
            istouch = False     #Присваиваем ложь
    sc.blit(player, player_rect)
    sc.blit(hud_surf, hud_rect)
    joystic(istouch,sc, mouse, mouse2, playerX, playerY)
    player_rect = player.get_rect(
        bottomright=(ЗНАЧЕНИЯ playerX,playerY ПЕРЕДАННІЕ ИЗ ФУНКЦИИ joystic ))
    clock.tick(60)          #Ограничиваем кадры в секунду до 60
    pg.display.update()     #Обновляем поверхность экрана
```

#main.py

```
import pygame as pg         
import math                 
import random
from pygame import image
from virtjoystick import joystic
sc = pg.display.set_mode((1720,1080), pg.FULLSCREEN | pg.SCALED)

istouch = False     #Создаем переменную чтобы знать нажата мышь\палец или нет
mouse2 = (-1000,-1000)      #Переменная для фиксированого значения мыши

playerX = 200
playerY = 200
while running: 
    mouse = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    for backend in range(30):
        for img in range(35):
            back_rect = back.get_rect(
            bottomright=(img*47, backend*47))
            sc.blit(back, back_rect)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:        #Если мышь\палец нажата
            istouch = True      #Присваиваем истину
            mouse2 = mouse 
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:        #Если мышь\палец отпускаются
            istouch = False     #Присваиваем ложь
    sc.blit(player, player_rect)
    sc.blit(hud_surf, hud_rect)
    joystic(istouch,sc, mouse, mouse2, playerX, playerY)
    player_rect = player.get_rect(
        bottomright=(ЗНАЧЕНИЯ playerX,playerY ПЕРЕДАННІЕ ИЗ ФУНКЦИИ joystic ))
    clock.tick(60)          #Ограничиваем кадры в секунду до 60
    pg.display.update()     #Обновляем поверхность экрана
```

#virtjoystick.py

```
import pygame as pg
import math
def joystic(istouch,sc, mouse, mouse2, playerX, playerY):
    if istouch:     #Если мышь\палец нажаты
        pg.draw.circle(sc, (100,100,100), mouse2, 60)       #Рисуем круг в нажатом фиксированом месте
        cur_mouse = mouse[0] - mouse2[0], mouse[1] - mouse2[1]      #Определяем позицию мыши\пальца относительно середины джойстика
        angler = math.atan2(cur_mouse[0], cur_mouse[1])     #Определяем угол курсора джойстка относительно середины джойстика в радианах
        distance  = math.sqrt(pow(cur_mouse[0], 2) + pow(cur_mouse[1], 2))      #Определяем расстояние от середины джойсткеа до курсора джойстка
        joy_pos = mouse2
        if distance > 55:       #Если расстояние от середины джойстика до курсора джойстика больше 80
            si = math.sin(angler)       #Определяем синус угла курсора относительно середины джойстика
            co = math.cos(angler)       #Определяем косинус угла курсора относительно середины джойстика
            joy_pos = (math.degrees(si)*1+mouse2[0], math.degrees(co)*1+mouse2[1])      #устанавливаем позицию курсора джойстика с множителем 1.4
            distance = 55       #Устанавливаем расстояние до курсора джойстка относительно середины джойсткка 80
        else:
            joy_pos = mouse
        pg.draw.circle(sc, (234,234,234), joy_pos, 25)      #Рисуем курсор джойстика на экране по позиции переменной joy_pos
        playerX += math.sin(angler)*distance/10
        playerY += math.cos(angler)*distance/10
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно же возвращать из функции всё, что хотите, и получать это в месте вызова функции:

```py
playerX, playerY = joystic(istouch,sc, mouse, mouse2, playerX, playerY)
...
def joystic(istouch,sc, mouse, mouse2, playerX, playerY):
    if istouch:     #Если мышь\палец нажаты
    ...
    return playerX, playerY
```